# timer function not working on IE 11 using jscript on apex page

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I am using IE 11 and Chrome 54...

I have the code as follows to display a timer on the browser and it works for chrome but IE not?

```
var display;
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer <= 0) {
                do_func(); // something
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000); 
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var tenMinutes = 60 * 1;
         display = document.querySelector('.time');
        startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
    };
```

I am displaying it on the oracle apex page (html text) type region as follows

This session will be closed in  minutes. Please save your work before session close!

Comment: displaying on Apex page as <span style="color:blue;position:fixed;font-size: 145%; font-weight:bolder;">This session will be closed in <span class="time" style =color:red;"></span> minutes. Please save your work before session close! </span></br>

Comment: what's the error message you get in the console in IE? That should help narrow it down a bit.

Comment: error IE console: Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector'

Comment: File: f, Line: 683, Column: 10 when i click on on it then it open          display = document.querySelector('.time');

Comment: have you tried with $('.time')[0] instead of document.querySelector('.time');

Comment: i just tried and same result

Comment: i think it looks like apex theme issue as i did try on other theme and it works for IE too. it is working for theme for company custom theme  but not for Bluejay - 22 * . i did try for other application and it works.

Comment: i tried as $(function ($) {
    var fifteenMinutes = 60 * 15,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fifteenMinutes, display);
});   instread of window.onload = function () {
        var tenMinutes = 60 * 15;
         display = document.querySelector('.time');
        startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
    }; and it is working on both chrome and IE11. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried as

```
 $(function ($) {
    var fifteenMinutes = 60 * 15,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fifteenMinutes, display);
});
```

instead of

```
window.onload = function () {
        var tenMinutes = 60 * 15;
         display = document.querySelector('.time');
        startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
    };
```

and it is working on both chrome and IE11. 
thanks